# VBA: How to search range of cells for value, and return the cells next to the location?

Tags: excel, vba

Hello all this is my first question so I will try my best to format this best I can.

**Quick description without specific cell names below**

I am trying to write a macro where a user enters a value(X) and a macro searches a range of cells for a value(X), and then the macro returns the cell values in the 3 spaces next to wherever the location of value(X) is.

A couple things that are making this impossible to solve are the fact that the user inputs the value on Sheet1 and the value is moved to Sheet2 by a formula, I can't seem to figure out how to use Find where the values I am searching for isn't already defined in the macro.

The other thing making this difficult is that the range is not strictly definable either, as the list could be longer or shorter than it currently is, and I can't know when it will change. So the range of the search has to start based on which List is input by the User and needs to go until it hits a blank spot.

For example: Range.("C7:D10") wont work because the user could enter new info that changes the working range as described below.

**Below is a screenshot with further explanation**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlnhg.jpg

So in this screenshot the cells C3 and D3 are imported values from Sheet1.

C3 is (=Sheet1!B2)

D3 is (=Sheet1!B3)

The idea is that the macro runs and searches  down column A till it has a match with C3.

Then the search function moves over two cells and searches down till it has a match with D3 or until it hits an empty space.

I don't know how to ask a macro to search based on an imported value, and I don't know how to ask it to search this weird certain range I need. The idea is that someone at my work could come along and add a row below C10 and add the necessary information and the macro would still work and search to C11 and there would be a blank space after to tell the macro to stop.

After the search finds a match for D3 it would return the values adjacent to the match to the corresponding cells at the top, E3, F3, and G3.

I hope this question is asked in a way that people can understand, I am very tired so can't tell if I wrote something that makes sense. Thank you for reading my post, y'all are the best!!

Comment: Your macro would just read the search values from the appropriate cells on sheet2 - it doesn't matter if that value is directly entered into the cell or is the result of a formula.  Do you have any code at all to share?

Comment: @TimWilliams No I don't have any code cause I just left work I am very sorry. I will give some code as soon as I get to work tomorrow in the morning. My code is all very bad cause I don't actually know VBA I just throw things together, I am not a programmer, just trying my best. I didn't know I should add code, I have never posted before sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Search Twice

[Workbook Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/66guzgdb2d9k618/vba-how-to-search-range-of-cells-for-value-and-return-the-cells-next-to-the-lo_54936480.xls?dl=0) (Dropbox)

[image]

```
Sub SearchTwice()

    Const cSheet As String = "Sheet2"   ' Source Worksheet Name
    Const cList As String = "C3"        ' List Cell Range Address
    Const cName As String = "D3"        ' Name Cell Range Address
    Const cListCol As String = "A"      ' List Column Letter
    Const cNameCol As String = "C"      ' Name Column Letter
    Const cFirst As Long = 6            ' First Row
    Const cCol As Long = 3              ' Number of Columns

    Dim rng1 As Range       ' Find List Cell Range
                            ' Found Name Cell Range
    Dim rng2 As Range       ' Next List Cell Range
                            ' Name Search Range
    Dim strList As String   ' List
    Dim strName As String   ' Name

    ' In Source Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet)
        ' Write from List Cell Range to List.
        strList = .Range(cList)
        ' Write from Name Cell Range to Name.
        strName = .Range(cName)
        ' Check if Cell Ranges do NOT contain data.
        If strList = "" Or strName = "" Then  ' Inform user.
            MsgBox "Missing List or Name.", vbCritical, "Missing data"
            Exit Sub
        End If
         ' In List Column
        With .Columns(cListCol)
            ' Create a reference to Find List Cell Range (rng1) containing
            ' List (strList).
            Set rng1 = .Find(strList, .Cells(cFirst - 1), xlValues, xlWhole)
            ' Check if List has not been found.
            If rng1 Is Nothing Then   ' Inform user and exit.
                MsgBox "The list '" & strList & "' has not been found", _
                        vbCritical, "List not found"
                Exit Sub
            End If
            ' Create a reference to Next List Cell Range (rng2).
            Set rng2 = .Find("*", .Cells(rng1.Row), xlValues, xlWhole)
        End With
        ' In Name Column
        With .Columns(cNameCol)
            ' Check if the row of Next List Cell Range (rng2) is greater than
            ' the row of List Cell Range (rng1) i.e. if a cell with a value
            ' has been found below List Cell Range (rng1) in List Column.
            If rng2.Row > rng1.Row Then   ' Next List Cell Range FOUND.
                ' Create a reference to Name Search Range (rng2) which spans
                ' from the cell below Find List Cell Range (rng1) to the cell
                ' above the Next List Cell Range (rng2), but in Name Column.
                Set rng2 = .Cells(rng1.Row + 1).Resize(rng2.Row - rng1.Row - 1)
              Else                        ' Next List Cell Range NOT found.
                ' Create a reference to Name Search Range (rng2) which spans
                ' from the cell below Find List Cell Range (rng1) to the bottom
                ' cell, but in Name column.
                Set rng2 = .Cells(rng1.Row + 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - rng1.Row)
            End If
        End With
        ' In Name Search Range (rng2)
        With rng2
            ' Create a reference to Found Name Cell Range (rng1).
            Set rng1 = .Find(strName, .Cells(.Rows.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)
        End With

        ' Check if Name has not been found.
        If rng1 Is Nothing Then   ' Inform user and exit.
            MsgBox "The name '" & strName & "' has not been found", _
                    vbCritical, "Name not found"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ' Remarks:
        ' Source Range is calculated by moving the Found Name Cell Range (rng1)
        ' one cell to the right and by resizing it by Number of Columns (cCol).
        ' Target Range is calculated by moving the Name Cell Range one cell
        ' to the right and by resizing it by Number of Columns (cCol).

        ' Copy values of Source Range to Target Range.
        .Range(cName).Offset(, 1).Resize(, cCol) _
                = rng1.Offset(, 1).Resize(, cCol).Value

    End With

    ' Inform user of succes of the operation.
    MsgBox "The name '" & strName & "' was successfully found in list '" & _
            strList & "'. The corresponding data has been written to the " _
            & "worksheet.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Non VBA Solution

1. Convert your two list ranges to tables
2. Change the name of your tables by (`Formulas Tab > Name Manager > Select Table/Change Name`). Specifically, you will want to change the names to your desired list name. (`Table 1 Name = List1` & `Table 2 Name = List2`)
3. Next, drop these formulas inside `E3, F3, & G3`

---

```
  E3 = VLOOKUP(D3, Indirect(C3), 2, 0) 
  F3 = VLOOKUP(D3, Indirect(C3), 3, 0)
  G3 = VLOOKUP(D3, Indirect(C3), 4, 0)
```

---

This wil update dynamically as your table sizes expand. you can also add as many tables as you'd like and this will continue to work.

In use, it looks something like below

[image]

*My last suggestion would be to nest each formula above inside an `IFERROR()`*

Answer (score 0):

One reason for being tired is that you tried to go for the kill before you had set up for slaughter. The solution below took an hour to prepare and 10 minutes to encode. Paste the entire code in a standard code module and call the function `MatchRow` either from the Immediate window (`? MatchRow`) or from your own code as shown in the test proc further down.

```
Option Explicit

Enum Nws                            ' worksheet navigation
    ' 01 Mar 2019
    NwsCriteriaRow = 3
    NwsList = 1                     ' Columns: (1 = A)
    NwsID = 3
    NwsNumber                       ' (undefined: assigns next integer)
End Enum

Function MatchRow() As Long
    ' 01 Mar 2019
    ' return 0 if not found

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim R As Long

    ' The ActiveWorkbook isn't necessarily ThisWorkbook
    Set Ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")        ' replace tab's name here
    With Ws
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(NwsCriteriaRow, NwsList), .Cells(.Rows.Count, NwsList).End(xlUp))
        R = FindRow(.Cells(NwsCriteriaRow, NwsID).Value, Rng, True)

        If R Then                                       ' skip if no match was found
            Set Rng = .Cells(R + 1, NwsID)
            Set Rng = .Range(Rng, Rng.End(xlDown))
            MatchRow = FindRow(.Cells(NwsCriteriaRow, NwsNumber).Value, Rng)
        End If
    End With
End Function

Private Function FindRow(Crit As Variant, _
                         Rng As Range, _
                         Optional ByVal SearchFromTop As Boolean) As Long
    ' 01 Mar 2019
    ' return 0 if not found

    Dim Fun As Range
    Dim StartCell As Long

    With Rng
        If SearchFromTop Then
            StartCell = 1
        Else
            StartCell = .Cells.Count
        End If

        Set Fun = .Find(What:=Crit, _
                       After:=.Cells(StartCell), _
                       LookIn:=xlValues, _
                       LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                       MatchCase:=False)
    End With

    If Not Fun Is Nothing Then FindRow = Fun.Row
End Function
```

The function `MatchRow` returns the row number of Sheet2 where D3 is found, searching only that part of column D which belongs to the list identified in C3. The function returns 0 if no match was found, either of the list or the ID.

You didn't specify what you want to do with the found row. The procedure below will return data from that row. You might use the capability to address the cells to write to them instead.

```
Private Sub RetrieveData()

    Dim R As Long

    R = MatchRow
    MsgBox "ID = " & Cells(R, NwsID).Value & vbCr & _
           "Number = " & Cells(R, NwsNumber).Value
End Sub
```

Being intended for testing only the above proc doesn't specify the worksheet and, therefore, returns data from the ActiveSheet, presumed to be Sheet2.

Answer (score 0):

### VBA Solution

I think the non-VBA solution is ideal here, but I will leave this here separately just in case. This should work for your situation assuming no values in your tables are blank.

---

```
    Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set Worksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim iList As Range, iName As Range
    Dim aLR As Long, cLR As Long

    aLR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set iList = ws.Range("A1:A" & aLR).Find(ws.Range("C3"), LookIn:=xlWhole)

    If Not iList Is Nothing Then
        cLR = iList.Offset(0, 2).End(xlDown).Row
        Set iName = ws.Range(ws.Cells(iList.Row, 3), ws.Cells(cLR, 3)).Find(ws.Range("C4"), LookIn:=xlWhole)
            If Not iName Is Nothing Then
                ws.Range("E3:G3").Value = iName.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 3).Value
            End If
    End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Set ws..., What:=ws.Range("C3"), LookAt:=xlWhole, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try the non VBA solution- I’ll debug this tomorrow